# Load exe file and call function from them in dos

Tags: c, dos

I have a program(A) and there is anather executable file(B) in the same folder. I must call function from this anther program(B) in my program(A). And all this must be done in dos. How can i do it or what i should read to do this? Please help.

Comment: Which dos? MS-DOS? DR-DOS? VxWorks?

Comment: Are you quite sure it is DOS?

Comment: It should work in the MS-DOS.

Comment: What are you really trying to do by invoking a function linked into another EXE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS-Dos is a 16 bit OS. The executables that run in MS-Dos come in two flavours: ".exe" and ".com". Think of the ".com" as a ".exe" with lots of default values assumed by the OS. The ".exe" files contain a header which is read by the OS to determine various parameters. One of these parameters is the entry point address. Only one entry point address is defined (and for a ".com" it is always cs:0x100) and that is the address the OS jumps to when the program has been loaded.

MS-Dos has functions to load another executable and run it, but it can only run from the address given in the header. No other function address is exported so you can't just call some arbitrary function in the other executable. There is no DLL system in MS-Dos.

So, in order to call some arbitrary function in the second executable, you need to create your own DLL style system. This is not trivial since the OS uses a segmented memory model, that is, the memory is divided into 64k pages and addresses are formed from the segment address added to an offset, e.g. segment*16 + offset. So, there are 2^12 ways to express the same physical address. During the loading process, MS-Dos has to fix-up these segment values to reflect the actual location in memory the program has been loaded to. Remember, in MS-Dos there is no virtual memory. If you were to create your own DLL system, you will need to do this fixing-up yourself for code that's bigger than 64k (code+data less than 64k can ignore segments and treat all address as just 16bit offsets).

If you knew the addres, loading the ".exe" using the MS-Dos API would still be tricky as you'd need to know the CS (code segment) address the executable has been loaded to.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer really good. It help me much, but this information less for me to solve my problem.

Comment: @Nerses: The answer I was trying to give is: it's really, really hard to do this in MS-Dos. Is there some other method you could use? Using the command line perhaps (e.g. b.exe functionname param1 param2)?

Comment: It must be done programmatically executing first exe must use functions from second exe.

Comment: @Nerses: Perhaps you could go into more detail about the problem. Does the second ".exe" contain state information? Do you have any control over the source code to the applications? Why use a second ".exe" at all? Why can't you combine the two ".exe"s into a single ".exe"?

Answer (score 1):

If your two programs are separate executables files then will most likely run in two different processes, You cannot just call functions accross two different processes, you need to use some **Inter Process communication** mechansim.

You need to start understanding the basics & make a start somewhere and **[this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)** seems to be a good place to do so.

Since you mention DOS as the target platform, DOS is a non-preempted single user single processing environment but still TSR's in DOS environment emulate the phenomenon of multiprocessing. To implement IPC in DOS you will have to arrange for the TSR to collar a software interrupt, and then communicate with it through that.

Comment: I should use second executable file as dll or like dll

Comment: @Nerses: Check the updated answer, Read through the link and then if you still have questions come back and ask and we wil be glad to answer your **specific** questions.

Comment: Is MS-DOS would not the only possible IPC been between the single active process and a TSR?

Comment: thank you. I don know how it will be work in ms-dos. Since  MS-DOS is not multitask  OS.